# Error in reading the Firebase: from firebase value to child

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created an event handler for the onClick button. When I click on the button, I want to transfer a pre-recorded number in the database to the price section.

My problem is that: when I click on the button and want to pass the value "pricecode" recorded in the database to "price". But it is mandatory that the `pricecode` is pre-recorded in the database.

[image]

```
String price = String.valueOf(db.child("User").child("pricecode"));
```

and instead of the value "1000", it writes a reference to the key there. Read more in the screenshot.

public void onClickB1 (View view)

```
    {
        DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        String id = mDataBase.getKey();
        String name = String.valueOf(textB1.getText());

        String price = String.valueOf(db.child("User").child("pricecode")); // PROBLEM

        User newUser = new User(id,name,price);
        //mDataBase.push().setValue(newUser);

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name))
        {
            mDataBase.push().setValue(newUser);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"empty text",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> String price = String.valueOf(db.child("User").child("pricecode")); and instead of the value "1000", it writes a reference to the key there.

That's the expected behavior since the following operation:

```
String price = String.valueOf(db.child("User").child("pricecode"))
```

Does **not** store in the `price` variable the actual value (1000) of the `pricecode` field. The code inside the `valueOf()` method is a reference, so when you're passing that reference to the `valueOf()` method, you get:

```
https://testkornze...
```

So there is **no** way you can read a value of a particular field that exists in the Realtime Database **without** attaching a listener. I answered earlier a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72224450/error-in-reading-the-firebase-value-pricecode) of yours on how to read the value of `pricecode`. So to be able to use the value of `pricecode`, all operations that need data from the database should be added inside the `onComplete()` method.

Comment: "all operations that require data from the database must be added inside the onComplete() method."
I don't quite understand what it looks like? Can I have a short sketch, please

Comment: How can onComplete be correctly combined with onCLick?

Comment: Perform the click only when the data is available. Try to take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774) too.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how to link onClick and onComplete. I'm already too confused.

Comment: These are the steps. Attach on click listener, inside onClick, add the code that exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72224450/error-in-reading-the-firebase-value-pricecode), and inside onComplete, use the value of `pricecode` tp create a new object, right?

Comment: Alex, thank you for your help! I will try to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex explained this code merely builds a reference to a path in the database, but doesn't actually read the value from that path:

```
db.child("User").child("pricecode")
```

To read the value, you either need to call `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` , or call `get` on the reference, as shown int he Firebase documentation on [reading data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once). Based on that:

```
db.child("User").child("pricecode").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", task.getException());
        }
        else {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult()l

            String price = String.valueOf(snapshot.getValue());

            User newUser = new User(id,name,price);
            //mDataBase.push().setValue(newUser);

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name))
            {
                mDataBase.push().setValue(newUser);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"empty text",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I tried your method, got "null".

Comment: What does "got null" mean there? --- Also: did you already step through the `onComplete` code in a debugger line by line, checking the value of each variable on each line? If so, what was the first line that didn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: String price = String.valueOf(snapshot.getValue()); 
Yes, there is a record in firebase and outputs a null value

Example:  
public void onClickB1 (View view)
    { *here is your code*}

Comment: I expect that the value of pricecode when clicking on the button (OnClick) will pass its value to price (user-price)

Comment: Null returns in user-price with this code (your fragment above)

Comment: What does `snapshot.getValue()` (so without the `String.valueOf`) output?

Comment: If  String price = snapshot.getValue();
Error: Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.Object', required: 'java.lang.String'

If String price = String.valueOf(snapshot.getValue());
Output: user - price = null
Although pricecode = 1000 or any value

Comment: Yeah, that's not what I meant. I mean if you just `Log.d(snapshot.getValue())`, what do you get in the output.

Comment: Error: Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.Object', required: 'java.lang.String'
I don't understand you, I'm sorry

Comment: If you `Log.d(snapshot.getValue())`, what does it output?